# Passing a matrix as a parameter by function call operator overloading

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

As I know function call operator overloading is used to pass arbitrary number of parameter to a function inside a class. Is it also possible to pass a 2-Dimensional array ?

something like this in the following code:**Edited**

```
    class harm_osc {
    vector< vector<double> >& m_gam;
public:
    harm_osc( vector< vector<double> > &gam ) : m_gam(gam) { }

    void operator() ( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double /* t */ )
    {
        dxdt[0] = m_gam[0][0]*x[1];
        dxdt[1] = m_gam[1][0]*x[0] - m_gam[1][1]*x[1];
    }
};
```

When we have a large system of equations there are a lot of parameters.

Here an example from [odeint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/harmonic_oscillator.html) library with some modification, with a single parameter:**Edited**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
/* The type of container used to hold the state vector */
typedef vector< double > state_type;

/* The rhs of x' = f(x) defined as a class */
class harm_osc {
    vector< vector<double> >& m_gam;
public:
    harm_osc( vector< vector<double> > &gam ) : m_gam(gam) { }

    void operator() ( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double /* t */ )
    {
        dxdt[0] = m_gam[0][0]*x[1];
        dxdt[1] = m_gam[1][0]*x[0] - m_gam[2][2]*x[1];
    }
};    

int main(int /* argc */ , char** /* argv */ )
{
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

    //[ state_initialization
    state_type x(2);
    x[0] = 1.0; // start at x=1.0, p=0.0
    x[1] = 0.0;
    //]


    //[ integration_class
    vector< vector<double> > par {{1.,0.},{-1.,0.15}};
    harm_osc ho(par);
    size_t steps = integrate( ho ,
            x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.1);
    //]
}
```

Thanks for any guide or comment.
[image]

Comment: You are assigning a 2d array to a value, why? Did you mean to make `m_gam` an array?

Comment: Your `harm_osc` is defined and declared differently in each code sample. Why is that?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes , m_gam should be an array, do you mean `double m_gam[2][2]` and `harm_osc( double gam[2][2] ) : m_gam(gam[2][2]) { }` ? @StoryTeller : I replaced the class in full code.

Comment: Code edited. It works.

Comment: Did you mean "overloading"?

Comment: @sehe: Yep. Edited Thanks.